# How to deal with missing values in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

Looks like I have 672 mission values, according to statistics. 
There are NULL value in QuotedPremium column.

[image]

I implemented Clean Missing Data module where it should substitute missing values with 0, but for some reason I'm still seeing NULL values as QuotedPremium, but...it says that missing values are = 0

[image]

[image]

Here you see it tells me that missing values = 0, but there are still NULLs

[image]

So what really happened after I ran Clean Missing Data module? Why it ran succesfully but there are still NULL values, even though it tells that number of missing values are 0.

Comment: `NULL` is a value, hence such entries are neither cleaned nor reported as missing

Comment: Oh yeah.  You are right. I just expected all nulls become 0's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is indeed a value; entries containing NULLs are *not* missing, hence they are neither cleaned with the 'Clean Missing Data' operator nor reported as missing.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are not really missing values, its a string NULL which is added to all these cells. So, in order to substitute these values with 0 you can use this below:

Use `Execute R Script` module, and add this code in it.

```
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1); # class: data.frame
dataset1[dataset1 == "NULL"] = 0; # Wherever cell's value is "NULL", replace it with 0
maml.mapOutputPort("dataset1"); # return the modified data.frame
```

Image for same:

[image]